# Living potato clock?

Tags: biochemistry, physiology, plant-physiology, electrophysiology, organic-chemistry

Could a potato stay alive and power a clock while growing in the ground?

I know how a potato clock works as a electrochemical cell [image] and involves chemistry, but I am only interested in a growing plants ability to grow and recover lost compounds, water or otherwise during this process while in the ground.

[image]

Side question:
How much power could come from one potato?
[image]
Source is in the picture.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is trivial nonsense.

Comment: I’m on the phone so I can’t cut and paste, but read the line in the Tour that states the purpose of SE Biology.

Comment: Cross-posted on Physics in 2016 by the same user: [A live potato light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277693/59991)

Comment: @David is this better?

Comment: Better. But I still regard it as off-topic. However others do not. Whether they will give you an answer is another question.

Comment: Copper is toxic. The potato may develop a toxic wound at the copper site until it made a barrier there. You should try for yourself, it's such an easy experiment.

Comment: @com.prehensible can you make an answer out of that so I can award you the bounty?

Comment: Muze, please stop reposting this question. You’ve asked it here before (https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/69376/potato-power-self-sustaining-medium-using-a-living-potato-plant-possible/69543) and on Physics as well (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277693/a-live-potato-light). If the answers are unsatisfactory to you in those places, please comment or edit your previous q’s rather than reposting duplicates.